# How to fetch the data member of Object Variable in excel macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this macro which fetches using Rfc connection. I am able to fetch the data but I require to split the data as per requirement. The screen shot below , The first Line shows The table from which I am fetching the data.

[image]

I have declared RFC_TAB as Object and I am fetching data into it.

```
 Dim RFC_TAB As Object
```

The Below screenshot shows the data.

[image]

I am moving the data into 
     str 
defined as Variant
i.e

```
 Dim str As Variant
```

[image]

But when I try to access specific entry in it.
i.e

```
 Dim str1 As Variant
 str1 = str.str(1).str(1 , 2)
```

It gives the following error

[image]

How can I get specific entries from

```
str
```

so that I can split it to display in excel cells . 
I am new to macro programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str` appears to be a 2d array of type `Variant()`. You have to address the correct index, try:

```
Dim str1 As Variant
str1 = str(1 , 2)
```

Better, try:

```
Dim str1 As String
str1 = str(1 , 2)
```

For extreme safety, try:

```
Dim str1 As String
str1 = CStr(str(1 , 2))
```

Given you know the `type` of the object you are addressing

Comment: `  str1 = str(1, 2)
    s1 = CStr(str1)
    str1 = Split(s1, " ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(str1)
    s1 = str1(i)
    Next i `                                                       It is working. Thanks This is the split string snippet code

Comment: What is this "Data" in the variant called ?? A member or dimension or element?

Comment: "The array itself is a single variable with multiple elements; each element can contain one piece of data." from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164778(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: The link was helpfull.

Comment: Now I am getting a run time error 9 Subscript is out of Range I just extended the code

Comment: `Dim s1 As String
    Dim str1 As Variant
    Dim str2 As Variant
    Dim s2, s3 As String
    
    r = 12
    rm = 12
    str = RFC_TAB.Data
    For index_split = 1 To vcount_add
    str1 = str(index_split, 2)

    s1 = CStr(str1)
    str1 = Split(s1, " ")
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(str1)
    s1 = str1(i)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 9) = s1
    r = r + 1
    Next i
    str2 = str(index_split, 5)
    s2 = CStr(str2)
    str2 = Split(s2, "/")
    For j = 1 To UBound(str2)
    s3 = str2(i)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(rm, 10) = s3
    rm = rm + 1
    Next j
    Next index_split`

Comment: I did some research on it and I found out...It is occuring because some of the files in the raw data folder are corrupted and get locked automatically. So when the macro on opening the file gets an error and stops there.

Comment: And it  occurs on this Line `For j = 1 To UBound(str2) `

Comment: I got it. It was my mistake. It is similar to out of bound error I was passing the wrong variable..."i" instead of j